# Inaccuracies in matrix multiplication- C

Tags: c, matrix, double

I'm doing a DS project in C.
I've been struggling with a matrix multiplication function:

```
void mat_mult(double **mat1, double **mat2, double **res, int n) {
    int i, j, k;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            assert(res[i][j] == 0);
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                res[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];;
        }
    }
}
```

The matrices I'm trying to multiply are:

```
0.00000000, 0.00007291, 0.00000000 
0.00007291, 0.00000000, 0.00000001 
0.00000000, 0.00000001, 0.00000000
```

and:

```
117.11258762, 0.00000000, 0.00000000 
0.00000000, 117.10123871, 0.00000000 
0.00000000, 0.00000000, 8087.59220061
```

The result is:

```
0.00000000, 0.00853872, 0.00000007 
0.00853790, 0.00000000, 0.00000172 
0.00000467, 0.00011897, 0.00000000
```

And not:

```
0.00000000 0.00853868 0.00000000
0.00853785 0.00000000 0.00000117
0.00000000 0.00008088 0.00000000
```

So, the inaccuracies are very small but could be significant. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve or what to look for in trying to solve this?

***Edit- generating code ***

```
int main(){
int i,j;
int dim=3;
int n=3;
double* a;
double** wam_res, **ddg_res, **lnorm_res, **test_res;
double** vecs;
vecs= (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
assert(vecs!=NULL);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    a= (double*)calloc(dim,sizeof(double));
    assert(a!=NULL);
    for(j=0; j<dim; j++)
    {
        a[j]= rand() %50;
    }
    vecs[i]= a;
    
}
wam_res= wam(vecs,dim,n);
printf("%s","wam:\n");
print_matrix(wam_res, n);
ddg_res= ddg(wam_res, n);
printf("%s","ddg:\n");
print_sym_mat(ddg_res, n); 

lnorm_res= lnorm(ddg_res, wam_res, n);
printf("%s","lnorm:\n"); }


double** wam(double** vecs, int dim, int n) {
 /*Calculating wam for the given set of vectors- n vectors of dimension dim */
double** res;
int i,j, curr_index=0;
double norm;
res= (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
for(i=0; i< n; i++)
{
    res[i]= (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));

    /*For vector i, calculating wij for all 0<=j<n*/
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(i!=j)

        {
            
            norm= l2_norm2vec(*(vecs+i),*(vecs+j),dim); /* function for l2 norm */
            
            res[i][j]= exp((-1*norm/2));
            
            curr_index++;
        }
        else
        {
            /* no self loops */
            res[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
return res; }

double** ddg(double** wam, int n) {
int i, j; 
double** res;
double d=0; 
res= (double**)calloc(n*n, sizeof(double*)); /* a n*n array with just 0s */
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    res[i]= (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        d+=wam[i][j];
    }
    res[i][i]= 1/sqrt(d);
    d=0;

}
return res; }

double** lnorm(double** ddg, double** wam,  int n) {
double** res, **tmp;
int i;
res= (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
tmp= (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    res[i]= (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    tmp[i]= (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
}

mat_mult(ddg,wam, res, n);
printf("%s", "step 1 results: \n");
print_sym_mat(res,n); /* errors happened here */
mat_mult(copyMatrix(res,n), ddg,tmp,n);  /*copyMatrix- simple loop to allocate an identical matrix */
res= copyMatrix(tmp,n);
printf("%s", "step 2 results: \n");
print_sym_mat(res,n); /* errors happened here too */
mat_subI(res,n); 
printf("%s", "step 3 results: \n");
print_sym_mat(res,n);
return res; }
```

The main function that calls the matrix multiplication is lnorm, that appears at the end of the code. It receives two vector calculations for different graph representations

Comment: Note: The inaccuracies occur in multiplication, as they also appear when I print each step and the scalar multiplication result

Comment: Post the whole code., we will not create the matrix-es ourselves. Make our life easier

Comment: fyi : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Please post how do you allocate, initialize and print the matrixes. Please create an [MCVE]. `what to look` well, `long double` is always there.

Comment: long double did not correct this.

Comment: Posted a generating code

Comment: Inaccuracies are not to blame here: the second matrix is a diagonal matrix so the matrix multiplication involves a single multiplication per element of the resulting matrix.  Your code outputs only 8 decimal places, whereas the values have more data.

Comment: ```wam:
  0.000000000000000,  0.000072910387337,  0.000000000577653,
  0.000072910387337,  0.000000000000000,  0.000000014710728,
  0.000000000577653,  0.000000014710728,  0.000000000000000,

ddg:
117.112587619035523,  0.000000000000000,  0.000000000000000,
  0.000000000000000,117.101238706028283,  0.000000000000000,
  0.000000000000000,  0.000000000000000,8087.592200608456551,

step 1 results:
  0.000000000000000,  0.008538724125301,  0.000000067650464,
  0.008537896671658,  0.000000000000000,  0.000001722644500,
  0.000004671823707,  0.000118974371006,  0.000000000000000,```

Comment: @ItaiZemah `copyMatrix()` missing.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: @ItaiZemah `l2_norm2vec(), print_sym_mat()` missing.

Comment: `mat_mult()` is not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inaccuracies are not to blame here: the second matrix is a diagonal matrix so the matrix multiplication involves a single multiplication per element of the resulting matrix. Your code outputs only 8 decimal places, whereas the values have more data.

Here is a modified version of the code that compiles and outputs the posted results, exhibiting the issue: the values in the matrices are rounded to 8 decimal places, which is a significant difference for some of the elements:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double **wam(double **vecs, int dim, int n);
double **ddg(double **wam, int n);
double **lnorm(double **ddg, double **wam, int n);

double l2_norm2vec(double *vec1, double *vec2, int n) {
    double res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double d = vec2[i] - vec1[i];
        res += d * d;
    }
    return sqrt(res);
}

#define print_sym_mat print_matrix

double **copyMatrix(double **res, int n) {
    double **mat = malloc(sizeof(*mat) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mat[i] = malloc(sizeof(*mat[i]) * n);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = res[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

double **mat_subI(double **mat, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mat[i][i] -= 1;
    }
    return mat;
}

void mat_mult(double **mat1, double **mat2, double **res, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            res[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                res[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(double **mat, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%19.15f,", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int i, j;
    int dim = 3;
    int n = 3;
    double *a;
    double **wam_res, **ddg_res, **lnorm_res;
    double **vecs;
    vecs = (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
    assert(vecs != NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a = (double*)calloc(dim, sizeof(double));
        assert(a != NULL);
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            a[j] = rand() % 50;
        }
        vecs[i] = a;
    }
    wam_res = wam(vecs, dim, n);
    printf("%s", "wam:\n");
    print_matrix(wam_res, n);
    ddg_res = ddg(wam_res, n);
    printf("%s", "ddg:\n");
    print_sym_mat(ddg_res, n);

    lnorm_res = lnorm(ddg_res, wam_res, n);
    printf("%s", "lnorm:\n");
    print_matrix(lnorm_res, n);
    return 0;
}

double **wam(double **vecs, int dim, int n) {
    /* Calculating wam for the given set of vectors- n vectors of dimension dim */
    double **res;
    int i, j, curr_index = 0;
    double norm;
    res = (double **)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res[i] = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));

        /*For vector i, calculating wij for all 0<=j<n*/
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                norm = l2_norm2vec(*(vecs+i), *(vecs+j), dim); /* function for l2 norm */
                res[i][j] = exp((-1 * norm / 2));
                curr_index++;
            } else {
                /* no self loops */
                res[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

double **ddg(double **wam, int n) {
    int i, j;
    double **res;
    double d = 0;
    res = (double**)calloc(n*n, sizeof(double*)); /* a n*n array with just 0s */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res[i] = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)  {
            d += wam[i][j];
        }
        res[i][i] = 1 / sqrt(d);
        d = 0;
    }
    return res;
}

double **lnorm(double **ddg, double **wam, int n) {
    double **res, **tmp;
    int i;
    res = (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    tmp = (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res[i] = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
        tmp[i] = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    }

    mat_mult(ddg,wam, res, n);
    printf("%s", "step 1 results: \n");
    print_sym_mat(res, n); /* errors happened here */
    mat_mult(copyMatrix(res, n), ddg, tmp, n);  /*copyMatrix- simple loop to allocate an identical matrix */
    res = copyMatrix(tmp, n);
    printf("%s", "step 2 results: \n");
    print_sym_mat(res, n); /* errors happened here too */
    mat_subI(res, n);
    printf("%s", "step 3 results: \n");
    print_sym_mat(res, n);
    return res;
}
```

Output with 8 decimal places:

```
wam:
  0.00000000,  0.00007291,  0.00000000,
  0.00007291,  0.00000000,  0.00000001,
  0.00000000,  0.00000001,  0.00000000,

ddg:
117.11258762,  0.00000000,  0.00000000,
  0.00000000,117.10123871,  0.00000000,
  0.00000000,  0.00000000,8087.59220061,

step 1 results:
  0.00000000,  0.00853872,  0.00000007,
  0.00853790,  0.00000000,  0.00000172,
  0.00000467,  0.00011897,  0.00000000,

step 2 results:
  0.00000000,  0.99989517,  0.00054713,
  0.99989517,  0.00000000,  0.01393205,
  0.00054713,  0.01393205,  0.00000000,

step 3 results:
 -1.00000000,  0.99989517,  0.00054713,
  0.99989517, -1.00000000,  0.01393205,
  0.00054713,  0.01393205, -1.00000000,

lnorm:
 -1.00000000,  0.99989517,  0.00054713,
  0.99989517, -1.00000000,  0.01393205,
  0.00054713,  0.01393205, -1.00000000,
```

With more places, it appears the coefficients in `wam` are quite different from `0.00000001`:

```
wam:
  0.000000000000000,  0.000072910387337,  0.000000000577653,
  0.000072910387337,  0.000000000000000,  0.000000014710728,
  0.000000000577653,  0.000000014710728,  0.000000000000000,

ddg:
117.112587619035523,  0.000000000000000,  0.000000000000000,
  0.000000000000000,117.101238706028283,  0.000000000000000,
  0.000000000000000,  0.000000000000000,8087.592200608456551,

step 1 results:
  0.000000000000000,  0.008538724125301,  0.000000067650464,
  0.008537896671658,  0.000000000000000,  0.000001722644500,
  0.000004671823707,  0.000118974371006,  0.000000000000000,

step 2 results:
  0.000000000000000,  0.999895172041842,  0.000547129363250,
  0.999895172041842,  0.000000000000000,  0.013932046219111,
  0.000547129363250,  0.013932046219111,  0.000000000000000,

step 3 results:
 -1.000000000000000,  0.999895172041842,  0.000547129363250,
  0.999895172041842, -1.000000000000000,  0.013932046219111,
  0.000547129363250,  0.013932046219111, -1.000000000000000,

lnorm:
 -1.000000000000000,  0.999895172041842,  0.000547129363250,
  0.999895172041842, -1.000000000000000,  0.013932046219111,
  0.000547129363250,  0.013932046219111, -1.000000000000000,
```

Comment: In follow up tests- indeed the results online converged to the C results the more decimals they were given. Thanks!